# index file stills showing even if i delete it

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I put a `index.html` file in the root of my amazon ec2 to show a maintenance message a while. When I delete the file the index.html stills showing instead of the `index.php` that contains the directory. Any though what's going on?

Comment: Clear your browser cache?

Comment: switching browser, can tell you if its a browser cache issue

Comment: Not a cache issue I think. I've cleared all the cache and the page still showing the problem.

Comment: please open http://www.targetjob.co/ and tell me if a grey window with a message is displayed.

Comment: https://screenshots.firefox.com/MA2wCGhKFObesW3w/www.targetjob.co

Comment: that's it. Not a browser cache problem.

Comment: it's curious because if I try to get /index.html I receive an 404 error.

Comment: Does Amazon EC2 have an area to set this index or something like this?

Comment: by the way the correct file I need to display is targetjob.co/index.php

Comment: works for me, no grey window with a message

Comment: *"it's curious because if I try to get /index.html I receive an 404 error."*  That's not actually curious at all, @CesarJrRodriguez.  The browser was never aware that the index page was stored at `/index.html`.  The browser cached the response for `/`.  As far as the browser is concerned, those two paths (URIs) have nothing in common.